# bubble sort logic error

Tags: c#

I was trying a basic sorting exercise and I was hoping I could receive some help with what is probably a basic logic error.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 2, 5, 11, 38, 24, 6, 9, 0, 83, 7 };
        for (int loop = 0; loop < numbers.Length; loop++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[loop]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Performing a bubble sort");

        bool flag = false;
        do
        {

            for (int loop = 0; loop < numbers.Length - 1; loop++)
            {
                if (numbers[loop] > numbers[loop + 1])
                {

                    int temporary = numbers[loop];
                    numbers[loop] = numbers[loop + 1];
                    numbers[loop + 1] = temporary;
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
        } while (flag == false);

        for (int loop = 0; loop < numbers.Length; loop++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[loop]);
        }
```

Comment: Please describe what is wrong and what you have tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. The first, as has been pointed out, is that you need to loop as long as `flag == true`. That would have been a lot more clear if you had given it a more expressive name. `madeASwap` or something like that makes it obvious: `do while(madeASwap)`.

The other issue is that you need to *reset the flag* before running the inner loop. Without that, just checking for `false` ends after a single iteration, and checking for `true` results in an infinite loop.

In short: reset your flag, and loop while it's true.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know everything that's wrong, but one thing for sure is that your do/while loop should be going while `while(flag == true)`, not `while(flag == false)`.  Which, of course, can be written more simply as `while(flag)`

Answer (score 1):

Your flag logic is wrong. Everything else looks correct.

The flag is supposed to mean:

`loop until we looped without making any swaps`

But that isn't what your code currently does.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here and migrate :

```
// array of integers to hold values
private int[] a = new int[100];

// number of elements in array
private int x;

// Bubble Sort Algorithm
public void sortArray()
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int temp;

  for( i = (x - 1); i >= 0; i-- )
  {
    for( j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
    {
      if( a[j-1] > a[j] )
      {
        temp = a[j-1];
        a[j-1] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition `while(flag == false)` should read `while(flag == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is not one pass sorting. In one iteration the biggest number moves to the most right cell. So after the first iteration the largest number will be stored in the last cell.

```
for (int l = numbers.Length - 1; l > -1; l--)  
  for (int loop = 0; loop < l; loop++) { /* your code */ }
```

And you don't need the `flag` (ok, maybe you need, but that not the mistake you've made)

Here's the output of the algorithm after each iteration:

```
2 5 11 24 6 9 0 38 7 83
2 5 11 6 9 0 24 7 38 83
2 5 6 9 0 11 7 24 38 83
2 5 6 0 9 7 11 24 38 83
2 5 0 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
2 0 5 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
0 2 5 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
0 2 5 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
0 2 5 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
0 2 5 6 7 9 11 24 38 83
```